# SharePoint Online - Display Shared with Info of the documents in search results

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I want the documents in search results to show the shared with Info besides the title in Sharepoint online. As seen in the image below, I want the part highlighted in Red.

[Display Shared With Info like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUUx8.png)

For example, the document is shared with certain user groups and if the user searches for the document in Sharepoint search, search results should show the document with title along with Shared with information. Is it possible to accomplish this in SharePoint Online?

These are the things I have tried so far

1. Updated the display template by adding Managed property "SharedWithInternal" to mso managed properties - didn't work
2. Tried JSOM to get the document properties and display it with the title - didn't work
3. Used CSWP and tried adding Sharedwith as managed property - didn't work

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: ok sure, can you help me with the question Display Shared with Info of the documents in search results